# Xorg crashing when touching system tray

Tags: unity, xorg, 17.10, thinkpad, touchscreen

A few weeks ago I've updated Ubuntu on my ThinkPad T470 (equipped with a touchscreen) from 17.04 to 17.10. I'm not a huge fan of GNOME so I installed unity again and everything seemed to be working fine.

Except there's a strange issue with Xorg crashing when I touch icons in the system tray (I'm not yet sure if any particular icon is responsible for that or it's the system tray in general).

I've never experienced anything like this in 17.04. The issue doesn't seem to be tied to one particular touchscreen - I recently got an external touch display, touching the tray icons on it also crashes X11.

There's one thing I noticed though - there's an old issue with Unity multitouch gestures ceasing to work after some time when Google Chrome is started and I am affected by it (I experienced this with 17.04 too). I can touch tray icons as much as I want before this problem will kick in and everything will be fine. As soon as the gestures will stop working, it will take just one touch to kill X.

Here's how a typical stacktrace looks like:

```
[ 21295.825] (EE) Backtrace:
[ 21295.825] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x4d) [0x555e637b937d]
[ 21295.825] (EE) 1: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x555e63601000+0x1bc119) [0x555e637bd119]
[ 21295.825] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f4f9d679000+0x13150) [0x7f4f9d68c150]
[ 21295.826] (EE) 3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (gsignal+0xcb) [0x7f4f9d2d00bb]
[ 21295.826] (EE) 4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (abort+0x16d) [0x7f4f9d2d1f5d]
[ 21295.826] (EE) 5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f4f9d299000+0x8128d) [0x7f4f9d31a28d]
[ 21295.826] (EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f4f9d299000+0x8864a) [0x7f4f9d32164a]
[ 21295.826] (EE) 7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f4f9d299000+0x8a73e) [0x7f4f9d32373e]
[ 21295.826] (EE) 8: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (cfree+0x6e) [0x7f4f9d32844e]
[ 21295.826] (EE) 9: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x555e63601000+0x5f7bf) [0x555e636607bf]
[ 21295.827] (EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x555e63601000+0x803b6) [0x555e636813b6]
[ 21295.827] (EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (UnmapWindow+0x19b) [0x555e636842ab]
[ 21295.827] (EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x555e63601000+0x4cffa) [0x555e6364dffa]
[ 21295.827] (EE) 13: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x555e63601000+0x52e28) [0x555e63653e28]
[ 21295.827] (EE) 14: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x555e63601000+0x56e70) [0x555e63657e70]
[ 21295.827] (EE) 15: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf1) [0x7f4f9d2ba1c1]
[ 21295.827] (EE) 16: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x2a) [0x555e63641b2a]
[ 21295.827] (EE)
[ 21295.828] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[ 21295.828] (EE) Caught signal 6 (Aborted). Server aborting
```

I'll be glad for any tips how to solve this issue or how to debug it (it's gonna be my first time digging into X).